# Tried to run php artisan migrate:fresh after install voyager it's give me this error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, voyager

**Migrating: 2016_01_01_000000_add_voyager_user_fields

Illuminate\Database\QueryException

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'jaleed.users' doesn't exist (SQL: alter table users add avatar varchar(255) null default 'users/default.png' after email, add role_id bigint null after id)

at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:671
667| // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
668| // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
669| // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
670| catch (Exception $e)

[image]

[image]

Comment: you are altering a table that does not exists

Comment: The table is exists

Comment: `Table 'jaleed.users' doesn't exist` with a SQL query starting with `alter table users` means 100% that you are altering a table that does not exists, believe me, and if you see that it exists, than you are watching a different database of the one that your laravel project is working on

Comment: Okay I understand  true it does not exist but I brought the voyager migrations file and put it in the default laravel migrations file and after that, I runed php artisan migrate it's work when it tried to run php artisan migrate:fresh it's give me this error

Comment: laravel by default should have in the migration folder the user table migration and the reset password migration

Comment: Yes  there are other users table below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YOu need first to migrate the default `users` and `password_resets` and then the `voyagers` ones. In order to achieve this kind of order, you need to rename those 2 tables with a date previous than the ones on the others migrations, so some date previous then `2016_01_01_000000`, so something like

```
2015_01_01_000000_create_users_table
```

Comment: Thank you I never paid attention 

Comment: @WaelKhalifa no worries, happens to everyone at least one time until you know it